What are the sizes of the 5 (2+3) screws on a Dyson vacuum cleaner "end connector"?
My children helped me to repair or clean a Dyson "end connector" (not sure what this is called in English, the thingie you plug at the end of the tube) and fled, leaving me the Dyson "connector" without the screws.
The 3 screws in the first picture are tiny and I cannot find a way to measure them, nor any details on the web. The two screws in the second picture could be a bit larger.
Would someone have the measurements or documentation?



Dyson should be able help if you contact them.  If not, take the thingy to a hardware store and try a few screws.  They probably are small metal(wide, deep threads) screws.

Compatible Model: Phillips screws for Dyson V6/V7/V8/V10/V11/SV09/SV10/SV11/SV12/SV14 vacuum cleaner power battery pack. T8 long screws for Dyson V10/V11 cyclone, hair dryer. T8 screw for Dyson vacuum cleaner brush head.

Found here: https://www.amazon.com/Compatible-Support-Cleaner-Battery-Attachment/dp/B0BKKRT4M4
